# Seeking C++ api to read/write PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, gdal, software-recommendations, c++

I need read/write geometry object from PostGIS.

Is there C++ library to do this?

Comment: From the client or server side? PostGIS itself is open source, download the source from their website. http://postgis.net/install/ or you can use the OGR objects in C++ with the PostGIS driver.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thx. I will try OGR.  Do you know where I can find example code of writing PostGIS? I only find one [reading example](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/archives/postgis-data-c-using-gdal-and-qt)

Comment: You could start http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html about the driver and its special requirements.. I don't do pSQL/PostGIS directly myself but can attest that the tutorial http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html has some *very* useful gems.. one thing I will say though is to be sure to link 'additional dependencies' to the GDAL_i.lib - many hours of frustration over that one.

Answer (score 4):

[libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq.html) allows us to connect to Postgres/postgis for read write operations.
If you have installed Postgres,libpq is already available.It would be available at installation path like **C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\include**
.

```cpp
//To make use in C/C++, you include these header files
#include "libpq/libpq-fs.h"
#include "libpq-fe.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

//Declare some variables 

const char *conninfo;
PGconn     *conn;
PGresult *preslt;
//Connect to DB

conninfo = "dbname = lebl user=postgres password=abcd1234@";

/* Make a connection to the database */
conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);

/* Check to see that the backend cfonnection was successfully made */
if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s",
        PQerrorMessage(conn));
    PQfinish(conn);
}
else
{
    printf("Connection Ok");
}
```

Comment: Good answer, though the OP does not mention Windows, specifically.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to insert geometry to postGIS with libpq. build the sql and call PQexec, amazing.